# stat_cor function in ggplot2: Print R and p-values on two lines

Tags: ggplot2, ggpubr

Is it possible to Correlation-values and the p-value on two lines instead of comma-separated as is the default:

```
default:
R=0.8, p=0.004

want: 
R=0.8
p=0.004
```

Answer (score 4):

The `stat_cor` function is from the `ggpubr` library (not base `ggplot2`).  Regardless, [the documentation for the function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.2.5/topics/stat_cor) has your answer, which is to use the `label.sep=` argument in `stat_cor`.  You can set that to `"\n"` to add a new line character as a separation and get the label over two lines.  See the example in the documentation with the adjustment:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

sp <- ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
   add = "reg.line",  # Add regressin line
   add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), # Customize reg. line
   conf.int = TRUE # Add confidence interval
   )
# Add correlation coefficient
sp + stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 3, label.y = 30, label.sep='\n')
```

[image]